# What is the type of a string literal in C++?

Tags: c++, string, types

For example, what is the type of the string literal "Hello", `const char[6]` or `const char*` ?

Comment: `const char[6]`.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "type"?

Comment: @nabroyan In C++, every value has a type. OP wants to know the type of a string literal.

Comment: @H2CO3 I know that, but he answered his question right in his answer, so I taught that he means something else

Comment: @nabroyan what makes you think OP answered his own question?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The type of the string literal `"Hello"` is "array of 6 `const` `char`".

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array of *n* `const char`”, where *n* is the size of the string [...]

It can, however, be converted to a `const char*` by array-to-pointer conversion. Array-to-pointer conversion results in a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: This probably explains why this code shows a warning `C4172 returning address of local variable or temporary`for this function `const char* const& f() { return "hello"; }` in VS2010. Do you agree with this ?

Comment: @user1042389 The pointer resulting from the array-to-pointer conversion is a temporary object. You are returning a reference to that object, so that reference is left dangling.

Comment: Where is the temporary ? "hello" exists in static memory !

Comment: @user1042389 The **reference** to it is a temporary.

Comment: @H2CO3 `const int& f() { static int i = 0; return i; }`compiles without a warning.

Comment: @user1042389 The *array* exists in static memory. The pointer that we get from array-to-pointer conversion is temporary. Just like if you have an `int x;` and do `(float)x` - the casted `float` is temporary.

Comment: @user1042389 for your example to be similar try const int& f() { static long i = 0; return static_cast<int>( i ); }

Comment: Why the warning then for this snippet `const char* const& f() { return static_cast<const char*>("hello"); }`?

Comment: @user1042389 Because the pointer you're returning is still a temporary object.

Answer (score 5):

The Standard defines it as an "array of n `const char`", so it's `const char[n]` (n is the size of the string, including the terminating NUL byte).

Section 7, § 2.14.15:

> A narrow string literal has type “array of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration.