# Concatenate integer with string to format string

Tags: c++

I have to concatenate integer with a string as follows, user will enter a number e.g. `1` and it will be be placed in string like this:

```
std::remove("C:/Users/pcname/Desktop/files/1.txt");
```

If user enters `2`, it's like

```
std::remove("C:/Users/pcname/Desktop/files/2.txt");
```

It's pretty basic but I'm having issue with this I tried to use `operator+` with this but that did not work.

Comment: Be more specific. Showcase the problematic code that "doesn't work".

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting.  I recommend the keywords "stackoverflow c++ concatenate string integer".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::to_string` to convert an integer to a `std::string`, then use concatenation

```
int file_num = 1;
std::remove("C:/Users/pcname/Desktop/files/" + std::to_string(file_num) + ".txt");
```

Otherwise trying to do something like

```
"C:/Users/pcname/Desktop/files/" + file_num
```

is actually doing [pointer arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299156/why-can-you-add-an-integer-to-a-string-literal) and will not produce the string you think it will

Comment: [Error] 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: And in case you cannot use >C++11, `boost::lexical_cast`

Comment: kindly elaborate i am unable to get your second point boost::lexical_cast

Comment: boost is an external library that you need to include in your project

Comment: but you (if you can) should use modern c++ that is C++11 and above

Comment: so if i dont want to use boost::lexical_cast how can i fix this any suggestions please.

Comment: Then you have to fallback on old funtions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590381/easiest-way-to-convert-int-to-string-in-c

Comment: i used this       std::remove("C:/Users/pcname/Desktop/files/" + std::to_string(1) + ".txt");
and  this is what i get  [Error] 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: That's because you are not using C++11 or above. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string