# Why an int* array can't be initialized directly but char* array can be?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Why an `int*` array can't be initialized directly but `char*` array can be?
I know they are not same but what's the exact difference that causes this to happen (please explain why)?

I know why it's not possible for `int* p[]` to be initialized directly.
I don't know how it's possible for `char* name[]`?

For example:

```
char* name[] = { "Mostafa Chamran", "Mehdi Zeinoddin", "Ebrahim Hemmat" };
```

and

```
int* p[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

give error: *invalid conversion*

I didn't know what to search to find a related question so I don't know whether the same question exists or not

Comment: because `"string literal like this"` is a `const char *` but numeric constants are not `int *`s

Comment: according to T.J. Crowder they are const char (no *)

Comment: `const char[]` is the same as `const char *`. It's only different when declaring variables

Comment: did you read all his sentence? How can a `const char` (a character) be cast into `char*` (a pointer)?

Comment: @user3783574: String literals are `const char[x]`, not `const char`. `"foo"` is `const char[4]`, for instance. `const char[z]` is castable to `char*`.

Comment: im not native speaker so do u mean it can be changed to by saying that its castable?
or u mean it is const char*

Comment: @user3783574: `const char[x]` isn't `char *` but can be cast to it implicitly ("implicitly" = "without actually writing something saying 'do this cast').

Comment: so there is a deference between BEING const char* and being castable to it i gguess?

Comment: @user3783574: Yes. For example, `int` is not `long`, but `int` can be *implicitly cast* to `long`. *(Note: If you don't do `@T.J.`, I don't get notified of your comment.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entries you're giving for `p` aren't `int*` entries, they're `int` entries, so the type is incorrect (`int` isn't `int*`). The [string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508173/157247) you're giving for the `name` entries are `const char [x]` (where `x` is the length of the literal*), which can be implicitly cast to `char*`, so the types are acceptable and that works.

Since your `p` is an array of `int*`, the entries must be `int*` or implicitly castable to it, just like the entries for your `name` array of `char*` are implicitly castable to `char*`.

---

(* `"foo"` is `const char[4]`, for instance — `'f'`, `'o'`, `'o'`, `'\0'`.)

Answer (score 5):

The latter expression is an array of pointers. The error indicates that you are converting int to int*.

The expression should be

```
int arr[3]={1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: i know that
 but what about char* name?why it can hold literals?
but int* p cant hold numbers ?
i mean why char* can hold literals but int* cant hold numbers
arent they same like numbers?

Comment: @user3783574: Because [the type of a string literal is "array of `const char`"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15508173/157247), which can be implicitly cast to `char*`.