# C++ Constructor -- pass by reference only works with const. Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

So earlier on today, I was catching up with good old C++ and when I was compiling my code it was not working. Like a few programmers, I started hacking about, and eventually found that adding the keyboard `const` cured the problem. However, I don't like hacking about a lot and want to find out why the code was working fine after adding the `const`.

This was my code BEFORE adding the `const` to the constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Names {
private:
    string _name;
    string _surname;

public:
    Names(string &name, string &surname) : _name(name), _surname(surname) {}

    string getName() const {return _name;}
    string getSurname() const {return _surname;}
};

int main(){
    Names names("Mike", "Man");

    cout << names.getName() << endl;
    cout << names.getSurname() << endl;
}
```

I was getting these errors:

```
names.cc:19:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘Names::Names(const char [5], const char [4])’
  Names names("Mike", "Man");
                           ^
names.cc:19:27: note: candidates are:
names.cc:11:2: note: Names::Names(std::string&, std::string&)
  Names(string &name, string &surname) : _name(name), _surname(surname) {}
  ^
names.cc:11:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const char [5]’ to ‘std::string& {aka std::basic_string<char>&}’
names.cc:5:7: note: Names::Names(const Names&)
 class Names {
       ^
names.cc:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
<builtin>: recipe for target 'names' failed
make: *** [names] Error 1
```

However, after adding the `const` keyword within the constructor `Names(string const &name, string const &surname) : _name(name), _surname(surname) {}` -- it seems to be working.

This is my working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Names {
private:
    string _name;
    string _surname;

public:
    Names(string const &name, string const &surname) : _name(name), _surname(surname) {}

    string getName() const {return _name;}
    string getSurname() const {return _surname;}

};

int main(){
    Names names("Mike", "Man");
    cout << names.getName() << endl;
    cout << names.getSurname() << endl;
}
```

Now, a few questions:

1. Why was the code not working without the `const` for pass by
   reference? Is it good practice to always pass by reference in your
   constructors, and if so does it mean we have to use the `const`
   keyword?
2. So if I passed by value in the constructor say:
   `Names(string name, string surname) : _name(name), _surname(surname) {}` does this mean that `_name` and `_surname` are null or are they
    the values passed. I know in pass by value, a copy of the variable
    is being made and changes are being made to the copy. But when does
    the copy get destoryed or out of scope? It is a bit confusing.

Thanks

Comment: Why would `std::string` objects be "null"? The entire purpose of the ctor-initialiser is to initialise members. Those members obviously go out of scope when the encapsulating object does!

Comment: It's shockingly difficult to find a duplicate for this, probably because they've all been downvoted to oblivion. I know I've seen this question a lot before.

Comment: Is it good practice to pass by reference in constructors? If so, why?

Comment: That's a completely different question.

Answer (score 14):

A [string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508148/what-is-the-type-of-a-string-literal-in-c) has to be converted to a `std::string`, which would be a temporary, and you [cannot pass a temporary by non-const reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am still confused by it all. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @CodeMan: Your code is the example. Is the problem that you did not realise `"a string literal like this"` is _not_ a `std::string` object? And/or that an implicit conversion results in a temporary? And/or that a temporary may not be bound to a ref-to-non-`const`? These are three separate considerations, all answered previously on SO. Though I agree this answer needs fleshing out.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I considered having a class with life-cycle instrumentation in an online-compiler's store generally useful and tried to "flesh" the *temporary* part "out" based on that instrumented class.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite difficult to add something to @CoryKramer's explanation

> A string literal has to be converted to a std::string, which would be
>   a temporary, and you cannot pass a temporary by non-const reference.

that would not just rephrase it.

Anyway, here's some instrumented code you (@CodeMan) could play with

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream& logger = std::clog;

struct A {
    A() = delete;
    A(int ii) : i(ii) {logger << "A(int) ctor\n";}
    A(const A& a) : i(a.i) {logger << "A copy ctor\n";}
    A& operator= (const A& a) { i = a.i; logger << "A copy assigment\n"; return *this;};
    // nothing to steal here
    A(A&& a) : i(a.i) {logger << "A move ctor\n";}
    A& operator= (A&& a) {i = a.i; logger << "A move assigment\n"; return *this;};
    ~A() {logger << "A dtor\n";}

    int i;
};

void foobar(const A& a) {
    logger << "foobaring const A&\n";
}

void foobar(A& a) {
    logger << "foobaring A&\n";
}


int main(){
  int i(42);  
  A a(i);
  logger << "ctored a\n===================\n";  
  foobar(a);
  logger << "foobared a\n-------------------\n";  
  foobar(i);
  logger << "foobared " << i << "\n===================" << std::endl;
}
```

[**live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ceb56499c868b48a) at Coliru's.

As you can see from the output

```
[...]
===================
foobaring A&
foobared a
-------------------
A(int) ctor
foobaring const A&
A dtor
foobared 42
===================
[...]
```

in the 2nd `foobar` invocation there's implicitly a temporary `A` ctored from that int argument, and that temporary `A` instance is passed into a different, namely the const version of `foobar`, thus as a `const A &`.

And you can also also that, right after that 2nd `foobar` returned, that temporary `A` is dtored.

Answer (score 0):

1- "Mike" and "Man" in your call to the constructor are temporaries and non-const references cannot bind to temporaries. 
Passing built-in types by value is more efficient and all other objects by *const* reference.

2- If you pass by value `_name` and `_surname` will have the passed values. The passed parameters copies are local to the function so they get destroyed when the constructor goes out of scope.