# I'm having some code reading issues

Tags: code-readability

I'm studying for C test soon, and I will appreciate your help with a few code reading I can't figure out myself, the first one is:

```
main()
{
    char *p = "Hello", *q = "world!";
    while (*p * *q)
        p++, ++q;
    printf("%c", *q - *p);
}
```

If you guys can help me understand the output and what is going on there that will help me a lot.

Comment: `while(*p * *q)` should probably be changed to `while(*p && *q)`.

Comment: This code seems wrong.

Comment: Hi, I checked the code again and this is it.. any idea ?

Comment: Another question please, if there is a statement : if(a & 0x8) and a is 15. how do I know if the "If" is true or false ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted seems wrong to me.

```
main()
```

should probably be `int main()` ([Declare main prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020362/declare-main-prototype)).

```
{
    char *p = "Hello", *q = "world!";
```

should better be `const char *p;` ([What is the type of a string literal in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508148/what-is-the-type-of-a-string-literal-in-c)).

```
    while (*p * *q)
```

while the value pointed to by `p` multiplied with the value pointed to by `q` is different from zero

```
        p++, ++q;
```

increment both `p` and `q`.

```
    printf("%c", *q - *p);
```

It is that the `printf` is not part of the while loop. In any case it prints the arithmetic difference of the values pointed to.

```
}
```