# Using gethostbyname function

Tags: c

I have a piece of code that use *gethostbyname()* function, which is defined this way:

```
struct hostent *gethostbyname(const char *name);
```

My question is very simple, is it possible to directly put the char value like this :

```
gethostbyname("10.11.22.4");
```

or do I have to do it like:

```
char *tab[10];

gethostbyname(*tab);
```

or, is it another way ?

Thanks

Comment: The prototype of the function assume to have a `const char *` as input. So you can use both forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508148/what-is-the-type-of-a-string-literal-in-c) the type of a string literal "this is a string literal" is  an array of  `const char`. Arrays decay to pointers, so this means you can use

```
gethostbyname("10.11.22.4");
```

without declaring it first