# Trouble with passing C string literals to a function while using a C++ compiler to compile the code?

Tags: c, string, const-string

I'm getting an error that says "argument type "`const char *`" is incompatible with "`char *`".  This code was provided by my professor and I'm not sure what the problem is.

I'm writing C but I'm using a C++ compiler because it is easier to debug if that matters.

```
int main() {
    int i;
    Dictionary A;
    char* str;
    char* v;
    char* k = (char*)calloc(100, sizeof(char));

    // create a Dictionary and some pairs into it
    A = newDictionary();
    insert(A, "1", "a");  // it doesn't like "1" or "a"



// here is the function:
// insert()
// inserts new (key,value) pair into the end (rightmost part of) D
// pre: lookup(D, k)==NULL
void insert(Dictionary D, char* k, char* v) {
    Node N, A, B;
    if (D == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Dictionary Error: calling insert() on NULL Dictionary reference\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (findKey(D->root, k) != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Dictionary Error: cannot insert() duplicate key: \"%s\"\n", k);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    N = newNode(k, v);
    B = NULL;
    A = D->root;
    while (A != NULL) {
        B = A;
        if (strcmp(k, A->key) != 0) {
        A = A->right;
    }
    }
    if (B == NULL) {
        D->root = N;
    }
    else {B->right = N;}
    D->numPairs++;
}
```

Comment: it says its the error is on the line where I call insert(A, "1", "a");

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Out of interest, what sort of debugger is it that works better on C++ code than C code?

Comment: Using a C++ compiler to compile C code is going to lead you into all sorts of problems which would not manifest themselves if you use a C compiler instead.  They are different languages.  C and Modern C++ are very different languages.  You're seeing an example of the difference between C and C++.

Comment: You can't compile C code with a C++ compiler. Whatever it compiles is **C++**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literals in C++ are always of type `const char[N]` where *N* is the size of the string with (or without) the null-terminating byte. They also can be implicitly coerced to `const char *` - hence your error about incompatible types. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508148/what-is-the-type-of-a-string-literal-in-c) for more information.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler He says he's using a C++ compiler.

Comment: Yes — I just re-read that.  I'm glad the OP finds it easier; it isn't in my view a good idea to use a C++ compiler for compiling C code — C and modern C++ are two very different languages.