# Cannot use std::string variable in RapidJSON function call

Tags: c++, c++17, rapidjson

I am all new to C++ and am running into an issue. I am using rapidJSON to create JSON documents.

```
void setKeyValue() {
        Value obj(kObjectType);
        Value key("key");
        Value val(42);;
        obj.AddMember(key, val, d.GetAllocator());
    }
```

Works as expected. But when I try to replace the call to key to make it use a passed in param, like so:

```
void setKeyValue(string myKey) {
        Value obj(kObjectType);
        Value key(myKey);
        Value val(42);;
        obj.AddMember(key, val, d.GetAllocator());
    }
```

The myKey in `Value key(myKey)` get a red curly underling in Visual Studio saying the following:

[image]

What is causing this and how can I solve it?

Comment: did you check if there is a constructor for `Value` that takes a `std::string` ? `"key"` is not a `std::string` in case that causes you confusion

Comment: Try: `mykey.c_str()`

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I guess that is confusing me then. What would it be in this case, an array of chars?

Comment: Does it work if you do this? `#define RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING 1`. See here for the [docs of the constructor](https://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_generic_value.html#a852788b35257762cd8d6c4bf5c5d77bc) you're using.

Comment: @RuudVerhoef string literal (not `std::string`, mind you, which is just library type from STL, i.e. it's not treated specially).

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508148/what-is-the-type-of-a-string-literal-in-c (note that arrays decay to pointers when passed as parameter, hence you can pass a literal to a function expecting a `char*`)

Comment: @acraig5075 that solved it! I have no idea why as I thought I tried that already after having found that suggestion in an other topic I found using Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get support for `std::string` by default. rapidJSON requires you to [specify](https://rapidjson.org/group___r_a_p_i_d_j_s_o_n___c_o_n_f_i_g.html#ga2f2eef0ee4477f3fe5874703a66e997f) you want `std::string` support.

```
#define RAPIDJSON_HAS_STDSTRING 1
```

Only then is this [constructor](https://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_generic_value.html#a852788b35257762cd8d6c4bf5c5d77bc) you're using valid:

```
GenericValue (const std::basic_string< Ch > &s, Allocator &allocator)
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON library you are using seems that doesn't work with string objects from standard library, but it works with const char*.

So you must convert string object to char* with the method c_str():

```
void setKeyValue(string myKey) {
        Value obj(kObjectType);
        Value key((char*)myKey.c_str());
        Value val(42);;
        obj.AddMember(key, val, d.GetAllocator());
    }
```

Comment: I just tried copying your answer however that might have solved the issue I had but still results in a red curly line underneath the same word saying: C++ no instance of constructor matches the argument list argument types are: (const char *). I am guessing I am still not passing in the correct type of data.

Comment: then you can force with a casting, I modify the solution